# Set Message Body of email with data from Firebase database in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a purchase order app and I have a table view that shows the current purchase order. I would like to be able to send an email with the data of that purchase order to the supplier.

I have everything working fine but I am unable to set the message body to data from firebase.

My firebase database looks like this and I would like to extract the name, info, quantity and price of each items in the list and populate the email with this data.

[image]

and this is how I am saving the data

```
func saveItemInBackground(shoppingItem: ShoppingItem, completion: @escaping (_ error: Error?) -> Void) {

        let ref = firebase.child(kSHOPPINGITEM).child(shoppingItem.shoppingListId).childByAutoId()

        shoppingItem.shoppingItemId = ref.key

        ref.setValue(dictionaryFromItem(item: shoppingItem)) { (error, ref) -> Void in

            completion(error)
        }

    }
```

I am using this code to present the email.

```
func configureMailController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        firebase.child(kSUPPLIEREMAIL).child(FUser.currentId()).child("SupplierEmail").observe(.value, with: {
            snapshot in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                let toEmail = snapshot.value
                mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["\(toEmail as! String)"])
                mailComposerVC.setSubject("New EDM Pro Purchase Order")
                mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)
            } else {
                self.showMailError()
            }
        })
        return mailComposerVC
    }
```

and was wondering if i could user a function to set the email body and then call the function in the line `mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)`

Alternatively if this is not possible I could create a pdf of the tableview and attach it to the email. I am not sure how this could be done.

Any help on this would be amazing!

Comment: Load the data first. Once loaded, then create and populate the mail composer.

Comment: Sorry, relatively inexperienced at Swift, how would I go about doing this?